# laravel send parameter in route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Is thier anyway to do somethins like this ,

in web.php

```
Route::get('/test', 'testController@test');
```

in test Controller

```
public function test ($url)
{
 //while $url store test in route 
}
```

I know only if I send parameter I have to use

```
Route::get('/{test}', 'testController@test');
```

UPDATE

I want to do something like this

```
Route::get('/test', 'testController@test');
Route::get('/test2', 'testController@test');
```

in my controller

```
 public function test ($url)
   {
     while $url store test,test2in route 
   }
```

**LASTEST UPDATE**

I dont want to use {url}

I want to make /test = $url  when I enter to url/test

In my web.php I use this

```
Route::get('/test', 'testController@test');
Route::get('/test2', 'testController@test');
```

The reason that I want to do something like this because I want to make 1 function that alll route can use In my controller I do this .

```
 public function test($url,$preview=null)
    {   
    //$url shoud be test or test 2
        try {
            $test = (isset($preview)) ?  test::where('test.id',$url)->first()

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return redirect('notfound');
        }   
    }
```

**I dont want todo something like this**

```
Route::get('/test', 'testController@test');
Route::get('/test2', 'testController@test');
```

and In controller

```
public function test($preview=null)
    {   
    //$url shoud be test or test 2
        try {
            $test = (isset($preview)) ?  test::where('test.id','test)->first()

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return redirect('notfound');
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Explain details what do you want?

Comment: I updated my question @MahfuzShishir

Comment: I'm not sue, I think it is not possible using get method. If you use post method then you send data in controller.

Comment: well , MethodNotAllow when i change to post method

Comment: When it will be post method you have to submit a form.

Comment: Can you share more code? From where you want to send $url?

Comment: sure I'll update

Comment: I Updated @MahfuzShishir

Comment: I dnt want to make 2 function @MahfuzShishir

Comment: I added a answer try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Route

```
Route::post('/test', 'testController@test')->name('test);
```

If you use blade.

```
<a href="{{ route('test') }}" 
         onclick="event.preventDefault(); 
         document.getElementById('test_id').submit();">
         Test Click
</a>

{!! Form::open(['url' => route('test'), 'method' => 'post', 'id' => 'test_id']) !!} 
     <input type="hidden" name="url" value="{{ $url}}">

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

In your controller.

```
public function test(Request $request)
{   
    $data = $request->all();
    $url = $data['url'];
    //do something with your url...  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine both elements

```
Route::get('/test/{url}', 'testController@test');
```

> want to make /test = $url

You can't, but you can have `/test?foo=$url` instead. So you keep your route like

```
Route::get('/test', 'testController@test');
```

Then add `Request $request` as controller method argument (and you remove `$url`)

```
public function test(Request $request) {
   ...
```

Finally you obtain your url with

```
$url = $request->input('foo');
```

Comment: I mean is their any way  my $url store test,test2  , I dont want to use {url} I want to make /test = $url